# Jquery and responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a `scrollTo` anchor link script on my website with an offset of -35px because my nav bar is 35px of height. Sometimes on different resolutions (smartphone or tablets) I need to change the offset value. How can I do this in this script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scrollTo').click( function() { // Au clic sur un élément
        var page = $(this).attr('href') ; // Page cible
        var speed = 300; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top - 35 }, speed ); // Go
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Make the height dynamic? `var navigationHeight = $(nav).height();` Then minus the variable as the height?

Comment: What `sometimes` means? Your navbar changes its height?

Comment: Yes depending on the screen resolution, the navbar change its height !

Comment: Oh and i forgot to mention, i do not know well js, i know how to adapt script, but i don't know how to add var or other things in it :-(   (never learned to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest general solution is to base your offset on the height of the nav bar:

```
$('.scrollTo').click( function() { // Au clic sur un élément
    var page = $(this).attr('href') ; // Page cible
    var speed = 300; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
    var height = $(...nav bar selector...).height();
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top - height }, speed ); // Go
    //                                                           ^^^^^^
    return false;
});
```

But if you need to adjust your JS based on media queries, you should use [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
if (matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
    ...larger screens...
} else {
    ...smaller screens...
}
```

This has the advantage that it will *exactly* match the media queries used in CSS. If you call `$(window).width()` it may not exactly match media queries depending on whether a scrollbar is shown for some browsers.

Comment: matchMedia is something I learned today, and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks dude i found how to use this ! Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You could just read out the different solutions but perhaps with a media/css query it's simpler. To get screen resolution in JS use screen object:

```
screen.width;
screen.height;
```

So you can check for the height, and do then different things.

Comment: Appreciate your comment, but  i forgot to mention, i do not know well js, i know how to adapt script, but i don't know how to add var or other things in it :-( (never learned to), i only have html/css knowledge ! Could you explain to me what i should do with this exactly ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to test for a specific width on your window element.

```
if($(window).width() > x) {
  // Do something.
} else {
  // Do something else. 
}
```

You can use this inside of your click callback to check for the state of the window at that moment.

In your code, it could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollTo').click( function() { // Au clic sur un élément
    var page = $(this).attr('href') ; // Page cible
    var speed = 300; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)

    var topOffset = 35;
    if($(window).width() > 350)
    {
      topOffset = 20;
    }
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top - 35 }, speed ); // Go
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: @grooves you are checking for the window.width, it's a differs from the screen resolution the OP asks.

Comment: I realize that, but screen resolution doesn't mean anything for what he wants.

Read this: https://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/

Comment: Also, @zzzzBov answer above is better than mine, check that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers !

For those who need to know, this is the answer :

> Blockquote

he simplest general solution is to base your offset on the height of the nav bar:

```
$('.scrollTo').click( function() { // Au clic sur un élément
var page = $(this).attr('href') ; // Page cible
var speed = 300; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
var height = $(...nav bar selector...).height();
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top - height },  speed ); // Go
                                                             ^^^^^^
return false;
});
```

But if you need to adjust your JS based on media queries, you should use matchMedia:

```
if (matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
...larger screens...
} else {
...smaller screens...
}
```

This has the advantage that it will exactly match the media queries used in CSS. If you call $(window).width() it may not exactly match media queries depending on whether a scrollbar is shown for some browsers.